# How to modify highstock chart so that it can be used for displaying ranks (Lowest values on highest points)

Tags: highcharts

In highstock chart, highest value is being displayed on the top and lowest values on the lower points, is there anything I can use in highstock so that I can show lowest values on the top and highest values on the lowest points as I need to display ranks. Lowest rank means highest priority so must be displayed on highest point.

Comment: You can [reverse axis](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.reversed)

Comment: Its working, but as I'm using area graph. It also reversed the area. I want area on bottom x axis and not on the top, is that possible. I can see highest rank on lower points but problem with area now.

Comment: Can you attach mockup how it shoud look like ?

Comment: I want to reverse area as well, you can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/3ap5mnbv/

Comment: I think what I'm looking at is not possible, but what else I can use here.

Comment: Is it possible to start x axis from max value and decrease it to lowest available value from json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the values go from lowest to highest you can use `yAxis.reversed`, like this:

```
yAxis: {
    reversed: true
}
```

For area-series, if you want the area to appear "below" the series you can combine the above with `plotOptions.area.threshold`. This requires knowing the maximum Y-value of your data.

For example your data is:

```
data: [[1418860800000,1],[1419206400000,2],[1419292800000,3],[1419379200000,1],[1419465600000,1],[1419638400000,5],[1419724800000,7]]
```

The maximum Y-value here is `7`. We can use that in our settings like this:

```
plotOptions: {
    area: {
        threshold: 7
    }
}
```

Using both of these options can be seen in [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/3ap5mnbv/1/).